# How i can detect JasperViewer processing report time

Tags: java, process, jasper-reports, ireport, reportviewer

we know jasper viewer need much time to process report according to the data that will display.
I want to handle it, with give the user loading information.
this my step :

1. Check ,is the viewer in process or done.
2. If in process, create JLabel and set text to "Loading report..."
3. If done, set text to "" or null

And the *point 1* , i don't know How to check viewer is in generating process?
Please help me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the call to `viewReport()` in a separate thread. Store an instance level AtomicBoolean, and set it to false once the report is done. In you client checking method, check this instance variable periodically to check if the report is done.

Example pseudocode:

```
public void YourClass {

private AtomicBoolean reportRunning;

...

private void getReport() {

    new Thread() {

     reportRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
     JRViewer.viewReport();
     reportRunning.set(false);

    }.start();

}

// Call periodically and update UI    
private boolean clientCheck() {

    return reportRunning != null && reportRunning.get();

}
```